# Ceiling fan with remote control and 2 wall switches

Tags: ceiling-fan

I have a ceiling fan remote control module with 2 outputs, one for the light and one for the motor.

[image]

Also, I have two wall switches.

I want one switch to give power to the remote module and the other to give power to fan light

But I want to operate the light with remote control too and if possible work like ale retour.

So I can turn on the light from wall and turn it off from remote control and vice versa.

Comment: Does the remote have a dimming function for the light and/or a speed control function for the fan?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel yes it has dimming function for light and speed control. But light dimming function can deactivated

Comment: Also, where are you on this planet?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel we have 220v where I live.

Comment: You mean Eurostyle 220V single phase then?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  yes

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this type of ceiling fan remote isn’t made for your situation, and won’t work as you’ve described.

The remote and its receiver were created as a solution for locations where no provision was made for switching fan and light separately.  It solves a problem for those that needed to use pull-chains to provide separate controls for fan and light.

This site doesn’t do product recommendations, and I wouldn’t know which to recommend for your location anyway.  The product you desire is available tho (at least it is in the USA).  Search “fan control wall switch with remote” (I got the best results with that search, omitting “light”, however most of the products in the results also had the light control.). This product is different and manufactured to replace wall switches, allowing you to retain from the wall control as well as using a wireless remote.

Comment: I disagree I can use an external relay to achieve what I want but I don't know how to connect it

Comment: It’s possible, however for true either-or operation you would need 4 relays total, 2 fan and 2 light, and there would be no dimming or speed control.  It would be easier/cheaper/simplier just to buy the product designed for your need.

Comment: the module will be always on power. I want only to control the light with remote control and wall switch.

Comment: I’ll do a diagram later, I don’t have my laptop with me at the moment.  Where is power source? at canopy or the switch?  How many conductors are available between switch and canopy?  The answers depend whether this can be done with one relay or two for light control only.